# Enzyme Installation difficulties

Tags: reactjs, testing, installation, jestjs, enzyme

So I've been using create-react-app and wanted to implement testing. So  I read and followed the create-react-app repo to install Enzyme. [Enzyme intsallation link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#running-tests)

I install and run the Smoke Test.

> npm test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<App />);
});
```

and then I get this error in the console.

> Determining test suites to run...events.js:167
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn hg EACCES
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:217:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:394:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:223:12)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:394:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19) npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
      "name": "jest",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

If I change the "test" script to:

```
"test":"jest",
```

then run

> npm test

I get this error afterwards:[Unexpected Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU7nN.png)

Please help, I've been at it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created a file `src/setupTests.js`

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'; import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'; configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

This is required and notice that enzyme-adapter-react-'version_specific'

Comment: I added the file, however I get a "Syntax Error: Unexpected Token {" in the import bracket of the setupTests.js file

Comment: at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)

Comment: make sure to add the presets {
"presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}